# Delphi webserver broke after multiple calls at the same time

Tags: delphi

I have a simple webserver written in delphi which fetchs data from the DB and retrieve in `JSON`.

There are 20 endpoints, I will post one of them:

```
procedure TWM.WMactGruposGetAction(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest;
  Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  ...
begin
  // Get query fields
  ...
  // Configurar resposta
  Response.ContentType := APPLICATION_JSON + '; ' + CHARSET_UTF8;

  // Look for grupos
  qryGrupos := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  with qryGrupos do
  begin
    Connection := dmDados.GetConnection(NomeDB); // Open the 
    Active := False;
    SQL.Clear;

    Open('SELECT * FROM ' + T_PESSOAS_GRUPO +
      ' WHERE ' + C_ID_LOTEAMENTO + ' = ' + IDLoteamento);

    if qryGrupos.RecordCount > 0 then
      JsonArray := TJSONArray.Create;
      try
        First;
        while not Eof do
        begin
          JsonObject := TJSONObject.Create;
          CapturarCamposGrupos(JsonObject, qryGrupos);
          JsonArray.AddElement(JsonObject);
          Next;
        end;
      finally
        Response.Content := JsonArray.ToString;
        CloseQuery(qryGrupos); // Close and nil the query
        dmDados.CloseConnection(NomeDB); // Close the TFDConnection
        JsonArray.DisposeOf;
      end;
  end;
end;

function TdmDados.GetConnection(DBName: string): TFDConnection;
begin
  FDConnection.Open();
  Result := FDConnection
end;
```

This basically does the following:

- Opens the `TFDConnection`
- Opens the `TFDQuery`;
- Closes the `TFDQuery`;
- Closes the `TFDConnection`;

**Note:** The `TFDConnection` is created at design time when the application starts, so every API call uses the same `TFDConnection`;

## Problem

The problem is that in my flutter app I call **three** endpoints at the same time (they pretty much do the same thing as this grupos one).
When I call each endpoint at a time it works fine, but when I go to this page that calls three endpoints at the same time. The webserver brokes.

The error messages differ but they were things like:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server
Access violation address at ...
Cannot connect to MySQL
```

And then the server never works more for any endpoint.

I feel like somehow the `TFDConnection` lost the connection and can not get it again. Any help?

Comment: You never told what webserver component you are using but I guess it will be multithreaded, so that means that the Get event lives in its own thread and you must take care about thread safety. The easiest way is to CREATE the connection and query inside the event and destroy them at the end, that way you don't have to deal with synchronization. Small tip: Never EVER concatenate your sql queries, learn about parameters, you are vulnerable to SQL injection at the moment...

Comment: What whosrdaddy said + you seem to lack `begin .. end;` block after `if qryGrupos.RecordCount > 0 then`. Although you indented your code `JsonArray` is created only when the condition is `True`, but the rest is evaluated unconditionally. You should also get a compiler warning that `JsonArray` might not have been initialized, if you don't use the variable in hidden (...) code. Please don't ignore those warnings. You could also replace the condition with `not qryGrupos.IsEmpty`, which better expresses the intent. PS: We don't use `with' statement in 21st century. It's more pain than gain.

Comment: https://jmeter.apache.org/ helped me immensely with concurrency problems on our webserver.

Comment: Sorry for the `begin ... end`, I missed it when passing the code to stackoverflow. I will deal with the concatenation. I am using `TWebModule`, is this multithreaded?

Comment: @whosrdaddy was right, the problem was that I was creating the `TFDConnection` globaly outside the event. I started to create the `TFDConnection` and close it inside the event and it worked fine!